# React Native iOS starts the development server but never connects and then just crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

So I run my react-native iOS app from Xcode or react-native run-ios like normal. The server starts and says "Loading dependency graph, done." as normal. The app boots up on the simulator and then stays on the splash screen for around 20 seconds then crashes. It never seems to be able to find the development server and it doesn't print any error in the console.

I haven't been able to solve this issue for the life of me today. I've tried every solution I can find. If someone has any insight, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: try setting up a `debugger;` under `ComponentDidMount` on your `App` component, and troubleshoot further from there.

Comment: @kenmistry the app never makes it to that point to run that because it's not even loading the bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I ended up updating everything... Xcode, react native (0.60), my node_modules, and cleaned and rebuilt and finally everything works properly now. Updating took some time but it was worth it.

Answer (score 1):

How to overcome :

- cd ios && pod install
- then Open in Xcode (project.xworkspace)
- then clean and build project with Xcode

Comment: Perhaps also add rm -rf node_modules && npm install just in case to your answer

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you .

Comment: I am not using Pods in this project. I have cleaned completely many times. And yes I have also re installed node modules many times.